# How to calculate dew point of air-water system

Tags: thermodynamics, phase, gas-phase-chemistry

I want to calculate the maximum water holding capacity of air at a given temperature (as in $\frac{max\ mass\  of\   water}{mass\  of\  dry\  air} $ vs temperature)
I looked up online and there are various models to do such calculations. However for most of them the temperature range is not more than 100 C. Are there any relations which cover a higher temperature range, upto 300-400 C? 
If not, is not possible to determine saturation point above the boiling point of water?

Edit: I am considering a constant atmospheric pressure. Thus, I want to check variation only with temperature.

Comment: Above the boiling point, water becomes a genuine _gas_, much like air. Gases don't have saturation points. They just mix.

Comment: You can get above 100 C by increasing the pressure of course.

Comment: @IvanVeretin Water becomes a gas above the critical point, not the boiling point.

Comment: @Chet Miller No, liquid water starts becoming gas by boiling, when temperature reaches boiling point. The water phase diagram. The critical point just means above this temperatures water does not form separate phases, as their properties at given p,T just converged to the same values.

Comment: The conceptual mistake is, that the holding water vapour capacity is property of air. It is not. It is property of space. The air is just an obstacle and bystander.( with slight difference due nonideality).

Comment: @Poutnik The boiling point of water is a function of pressure, so 100 C is no magical number.  The terminology I was taught is that water in the gas phase at temperatures below the critical temperature is referred to as a "vapor," but above the critical temperature, it is referred to as a "gas."

Comment: @Chet Miller Notice that I have not mentioned 100C at all. So you say air contains CO2 vapours, as it is below its critical point, correct ? A vapour is just naming for gaseous phase of a substance, that we implicitly consider being in condensed phase. By other words, every vapour is a gas in sense of chemistry and physics. The terminology of technology and citizen life may differ.

Comment: BTW, the maximal mass of water in given mass of air at given temperature is reciprocally proportional to pressure. 0.5 atm air can contain twice as much water than 1 atm air and 4 times more than 2 atm air. So the original question does not make much sense.

Comment: To clarify, I am considering all this at atmospheric pressure. I just want to see the variation with temperature

Answer (score 2):

> How to calculate dew point of air-water system? I want to calculate the maximum water holding capacity of air ... However for most of them the temperature range is not more than 100 C. Are there any relations which cover a higher temperature range, up to 300-400° C? If not, is it not possible to determine saturation point above the boiling point of water?

At very high temperatures I could only find the Mollier enthalpy-entropy chart (for steam) here's one for up to 1931.67 degrees [rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale) (800 degrees celsius) and another for up to 2200 degrees rankine (949.072 degrees celsius):

[image: Mollier H-S (enthalpy-entropy) diagram for water and steam]
<sup><sup>Source: "[Mollier H-S Diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HS-Wasserdampf_engl.png)"</sup></sup>

[image: xxxxxxxx]
<sup><sup>Source: "[Mollier enthalpy-entropy chart for steam, US units](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mollier_enthalpy_entropy_chart_for_steam_-_US_units.svg)"</sup></sup>

Source: Wikipedia - [Enthalpy–entropy chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy%E2%80%93entropy_chart)

> On the diagram, lines of constant pressure, constant temperature and volume are plotted, so in a two-phase region, the lines of constant pressure and temperature coincide. Thus, coordinates on the diagram represent entropy and heat.
>
> The Mollier diagram coordinates are enthalpy $h$ and humidity ratio $x$. The enthalpy coordinate is skewed and the constant enthalpy lines are parallel and evenly spaced.

See the Wikipedia webpage for more information, or assistance reading the diagram.

For restricted ranges (of which you complained, but are useful for comparison and to view the *bottom* of the chart) see Wikipedia's webpage for "[Psychrometric charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychrometrics#Psychrometric_charts)":

[image: Psychrometric Chart for Sea-level pressure using SI units]
<sup><sup>Source: "[Psychrometric Chart for Sea-level pressure using SI units](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PsychrometricChart.SeaLevel.SI.svg)"</sup></sup>

Wikipedia's webpage for "[dew point temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point#Extreme_values)" shows some calculations and means to make simple estimates, but it cuts you off at 100°C.